# React Native useState onChangeText

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Hi I'm wondering why this code works,
Sorry for the sintax errors, this is an Example. My question is why **memberIpAssignments** is taking **ip** value?. I don't get it if I'm no passing **ip** into **setMemberIpAssignments(arr =>[...arr])** but still takes that's value and updating the state.

**setMemberIpAssignments(arr =>[...arr])**, this state shouldn't change at all, because I'm no giving **ip** value. But it does change taking **ip** value.
if someone can explain to me I'll be grateful.
I'm new at react-native

```
export const zeroTierNetworkMembersUpdateScreen = ({ route }) => {
  const { ipAssignments } = ["192.168.0.1","192.168.1.1"];
  const [memberIpAssignments, setMemberIpAssignments] =(ipAssignments);

  return (
    <View style={styles.viewSet}>
     {memberIpAssignments.map((eachIpAssignments, index) => {
        return (
          <Input
            key={index}
            placeholder={"ipAssignments"}
            keyboardType={"default"}
            value={eachIpAssignments}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              var ip = ipAssignments;
              ip[index] = value;
              setMemberIpAssignments(arr =>[...arr]);
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. You're using object destructuring to an array. That will return undefined on ipAssignments variable. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Syntax errors aside, you are using a functional state update. It is a function that is passed the previous state for you to work with. `setMemberIpAssignments(arr =>[...arr])` is simply taking the previous state array and spreading it into a new array reference and returning it. It's not doing anything other than triggering rerenders.

Comment: Sorry for the sintax error, this is an Example, the real code is an array. My point is why  "memberIpAssignments" is taking "ip" value?. I don't get it if I'm no passing "ip" into "setMemberIpAssignments" but still takes that's value and updating the state.

Comment: If I had to say, it is object mutation. You initialize your state with `ipAssignments` and you are directly mutating that `ipAssignments` object in the `onChangeText` handler. The `setMemberIpAssignments(arr =>[...arr]);` is just reassigning the array reference and triggering a rerender, thus exposing the unintentional mutation side-effect and you see the updated data.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've confirmed my suspicions that you are in fact mutating an object reference that you've stored in local component state.

```
export const zeroTierNetworkMembersUpdateScreen = ({ route }) => {
  // (1) ipAssignments array reference
  const ipAssignments = ["192.168.0.1", "192.168.1.1"];

  // (2) memberIpAssignments references ipAssignments
  const [memberIpAssignments, setMemberIpAssignments] = useState(ipAssignments);

  return (
    <View style={styles.viewSet}>
     {memberIpAssignments.map((eachIpAssignments, index) => {
        return (
          <Input
            key={index}
            placeholder={"ipAssignments"}
            keyboardType={"default"}
            value={eachIpAssignments} // (3) value from memberIpAssignments
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              // (4) ip references ipAssignments & memberIpAssignments
              var ip = ipAssignments;
              // (5) element mutation!!
              ip[index] = value;
              // (6) state update to trigger rerender
              setMemberIpAssignments(arr => [...arr]);
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

As far as I can tell the mutation happens ***exactly*** once since initially everything is reference the original `ipAssignments` array. Upon updating state though, `arr => [...arr]` is returning a *new* array reference for `memberIpAssignments` the references back to `ipAssignments` is broken.

You should really be using a functional state update to "edit" the ip entry any way. Consider the following:

```
export default function App() {
  const ipAssignments = ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.1.1'];
  const [memberIpAssignments, setMemberIpAssignments] = React.useState(
    ipAssignments
  );

  return (
    <View>
      {memberIpAssignments.map((eachIpAssignments, index) => {
        return (
          <TextInput
            key={index}
            placeholder={'ipAssignments'}
            keyboardType={'default'}
            value={eachIpAssignments}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
              setMemberIpAssignments((arr) =>
                arr.map((el, i) => (i === index ? value : el))
              );
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/react-native-usestate-onchangetext)